# Can I get cash from my voucher?

Tags: money, united-airlines

I have a voucher from United Airlines worth $300. I was given this because I voluntarily gave up my seat on a full flight. Is it possible that I can exchange my voucher to receive the $300 cash instead? The voucher doesn't expire until February 2016.

Comment: Find a friend of family member who'll be travelling on United, and get them to give you something in the range $200-$300 for it?

Answer (score 5):

There's a reason they gave you a voucher rather than cash--the voucher isn't worth anything like what the cash would have been worth.  They're not going to let you trade it in!

Answer (score 3):

I received a United voucher for giving up a seat a year ago, and assuming they haven't changed on the meantime, here are the terms and conditions I was given:

[image: Scan of United's voucher terms and conditions]

In particular, #3 seems to tell me that you can't use the voucher for anything but credit toward a flight ticket:

> 3. The certificate may be redeemed for credit up to its face value **only toward the purchase of an electronic airline ticket/s/**- where eligible- from United.

I don't believe you'll be able to exchange it. However, it won't cost you anything but your free time to call United's customer service line and ask.